# Derived class of b2Body or class containing a b2Body object?

Tags: c++, inheritance, box2d

I currently have a class 'WorldObject' which contains a pointer to its b2Body, and several methods and variables.

But wouldnt it be smarter to make WorldObject a derived class of the b2Body?

What is the general approach to that sort of things? To Always create a derived class of the most important object in the class, or to just create a new one and make everything attributes?

What are the pros and cons of these possibilities?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually better to do composition and not to overuse inheritance.

Note also that you usually create a body calling `b2World::CreateBody()` and that returns a `b2Body*`, and with inheritance that would not be possible.

To avoid the problems with the lifetime of the inner `b2Body*` you can use smart pointers. I use this definition:

```
class BodyDeleter
{
public:
    BodyDeleter()
        :m_world(NULL)
    {}
    BodyDeleter(b2World *world)
        :m_world(world)
    {}
    void operator()(b2Body *body)
    {
        if (m_world)
            m_world->DestroyBody(body);
    }
private:
    b2World *m_world;
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<b2Body, BodyDeleter> b2BodyPtr;
```

Then, in my `WorldObject`:

```
class WorldObject
{
protected:
    WorldObject(b2World *world)
    :m_body(NULL, m_world)
    {}
   b2BodyPtr m_body;
};
```

And then, in the actual subclasses of `WorldObject`:

```
class SpaceShip : public WorldObject
{
public:
    SpaceShip(b2World *world)
    :WorldObject(world)
    {
        //initialize bodydef and whatever
        m_body.reset(world->CreateBody(...));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no best way. It all depends on the context:

- Having a pointer to `b2Body` implements a composition relationship, i.e.  a `WorldObject` has a `b2Body`.
- Making `WorldObject` derive from `b2Body` implemetns inheritance, and shall only be done if a `WorldObject` is a `b2Body`.  This means that in principle you can do with a `WorldObject` object everything that you could do with a `b2Boby` (and more).

The rule of thumb would be to go for [preferring composition over inheritance](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose).  Unless you really have an obvious inheritance.

In your case,  a [`b2Body`](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/1.0/Box2D/html/classb2_body.html) is a rigid body.  Now a question for you:  is your object a body ?  Or has your object a body ?

More practical:  the advantage of this design is that it encapsulates the choice of Box2D engine in your `WorldObject`.  This allows you to control better the impacts if later you'd port your software to another physical engine using another API.   If you'd use inheritance instead, the underlying engine API would significantly impact the design of your own software and make it very difficult to migrate to another engine one day.

Answer (score 0):

You must prefer, composition over inheritance. The composition avoid the [fragile base class problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class).

- Unlike method invocation, inheritance violates encapsulation
- Subclasses depend on their superclasses, which could be changed and as result broken functionality in subclasses
- Use composition and forwarding instead of inheritance, especially if an appropriate interface to implement a wrapper class exists.
- Use inheritance when class is designed for inheritance

I suggest you to read the item 16 "favor composition over inheritance" of The "Effective Java" book by Joshua bloch